# Web api get method not respond

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I`m working on a .NET web-api project, I have a Car controller that has a method with a string parameter.

when I am using that method it returns all the data (all the cars) .

I tried to do it with "Where(...)" and it did not help.
I also deleted the model and the controllers(that I created a backup for)
and it worked (it was on an other controller..),but i cant delete the model each time it happens.
Also the debugger doesn't respond to it.

```
        {
            Car car = LuxuryWheelsDB.Cars.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Model==model);
            if (car != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, car);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
```

```
public partial class Car 
{ 
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; } 
    public string Model { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<double> Price_for_day { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<int> Penalty_price__day_ { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<int> Manufacturer_year { get; set; } 
    public string Gear { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Code looks correct. You sure you are hitting that method in debugger?

Comment: Is the s.Model an object or a string ?

Comment: @SteveGreene yes the code is correct is the same code id work with int parameters and it works,the debugger not respond when I call the method.

Comment: @azharuddinirfani what where can I see the s.Model? ```public partial class Car
    {
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Price_for_day { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Penalty_price__day_ { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Manufacturer_year { get; set; }
        public string Gear { get; set; }
    }``` you mean that?

Comment: please do not add code in comments, I added it to your post so it's clear what it looks like. you can delete the comment

Comment: If you have set a breakpoint and you are not hitting it, you have some sort of routing issue. Tools like [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) are very helpful debugging services.